# Linear combination of function objects in python

Tags: python

**Problem:** I want to numerically integrate a function `f(t,N)` that may be written as a linear combination of N other known functions `g_1(t), ..., g_N(t)`.

**My Solution I:** I know the functions `g_i` and also the coefficients, so my initial idea was to create an row vector of coefficients and a column vector containing the lambda functions `g_i` and then use `np.dot` for the inner product to get the function object I want. Unfortunately, you cannot just add two function objects nor multiply a function object by a scalar.

**My Solution II:** Of course I can do something like (basically defining point wise what I want):

```
def f(t,N,a,g):
"""
a = numpy array of coefficients
g = numpy array of lambda functions corresponding to functions g_i 
"""
    res = 0
    for i in xrange(N):
        res += a[i] * g[i](t)
    return res
```

But the `for` loop is of course not very great, especially when:

1. I need to run this function at many many time steps t
2. I pass this function f into a numerical integration routine like scipy.integrate.quad.

Comment: If your `g[i]` are polynomials then you can easily combine them in advance using a polynomial class. But if they aren't then I think you're stuck with calling them in a loop for each `t`.

Comment: how about using numexpr, cython, theano or sympy?

Comment: @PM2Ring: They are sines and cosines and form a truncated basis of L^2[0,1]. So there is really no way to call an array of lambda functions at once?

Comment: @RobertGrzelka: Could you maybe elaborate a bit on how these could be useful?

Answer (score 0):

briefly:

In Cython You could speed up indexing using memoryviews.

If these equations are linear You could superimpose them using sympy:

example:

```
import sympy as sy
x,y = sy.symbols('x y')

g0 = x*0.33 + 6
g1 = x*0.72 + 1.3
g2 = x*11.2 - 6.5
gn = x*3.3 - 7.3

G = [g0,g1,g2,gn]
#this is superimposition
print sum(G).subs(x,15.1)
print sum(gi.subs(x,15.1) for gi in G)
'''
output:
228.305000000000
228.305000000000
'''
```

If its not what You want, give some example input and output, so that I can try and dont go blind...

With low ram avaiable You could get finall equation to numexpr and evaluate it with some input. Otherwise its best to work on numpy arrays.